# Getting value type of string (JSContext evaluateScript)

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, javascriptcore

I'm running some code that is inputed by a user in `JSContext` and evaluating it. I would like to be able to get the type of evaluated result. I've tried a number of things (see below) but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions on how to do this? Would really hate to have to parse the string and try and classify it that way because I allow complex structs so e.g. `array.length` would be an `Int` and not a `Array` so it would take quite a bit of code.

```
let context = JSContext()!
let ans = context.evaluateScript(value) // need type for this

if let typeCheck = ans as? String {
     // always fails               
}

let y = "1"
print(x is Int) // false
print(type(of: y) == type(of: 1)) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

> Instad of js context you can use WKWebView evaluate java script.
>   something like this

self.webView.evaluateJavaScript(self.scriptValue)

> Let me know if it helps or you need to ask something.

Answer (score 0):

JSValue has `toNumber()`, `toBool()`... methods (and `isNumber`, `isBool`... flags for type checking).

```
let value: JSValue = jsContext.evaluateScript("1 + 2")

if value.isNumber {
    let number: NSNumber = value.toNumber()
    number is Int // true
}
```